# How do I filter certain lines from a log4j stack trace?

Tags: log4j, filtering

I want to filter out certain lines from stack traces using log4j (like `net.sf.cglib.*` and `org.springframework.*`). Is it possible to configure this with `log4j`?

In eclipse the junit plugin allows you to add filters which modify the stack traces displayed in the junit tab, but this doesn't change the stack traces output to the console.

Comment: You can't mod the normal log4j.properties or xml file? You can add -Dlog4j.debug to find out the config file it's using

Comment: Oh sorry stack traces, just read the question properly. Never done that myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this filtering layout log4j add-on:
http://www.openmindlab.com/lab/tools/openutilslog4j/layout.html

They have an example with log4j.xml on that page.  Just use the it.openutils.log4j.FilteredPatternLayout instead of the log4j PatternLayout, and then put some entries like

```
    <param name="Filter" value="net.sf.cglib"/>
    <param name="Filter" value="org.springframework"/>
```

below.

Comment: Seems [Log4J 2 PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) has a similar feature documented as a `%ex{filters(package,list)}` syntax but it's not yet implemented - at least as per 2.17.1

Comment: @Janaka Bandara How can you tell whether it's implemented? Have they fixed it yet  in `v2.20.0`?

Comment: Ok If figured it out - you can do this `%xEx{filters(${filters})}`. They have an example [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.8.2/manual/layouts.html). `<properties>
  <property name="filters">org.junit,org.apache.maven,sun.reflect,java.lang.reflect</property>
</properties>
...
<PatternLayout pattern="%m%xEx{filters(${filters})}%n"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for future viewers using log4j2 who may be wondering this. (I'm using log4j2 v2.20.0 at the time of writing)

To filter certain packages from a stacktrace, you'll need to specify a list of packages and use the `%xEx{filters(${filters})}` directive within your pattern to specify the lines to filter:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="STACKTRACE_EXCLUDE">
            java.base,
            java.lang,
            javax.servlet,
            jdk.internal,
            org.apache,
            org.springframework,
        </Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} %highlight{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=green, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue} %style{${sys:PID}}{magenta} [%15.15t][%X{dd.trace_id}][%X{dd.span_id}] %style{%-40.40C{1.}}{cyan} : %m%xEx{filters(${STACKTRACE_EXCLUDE})}%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.mongodb.driver" level="warn"/>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

After adding that, you should see the stacktraces starting to look like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: oh no test exception
    at com.company.controller.MyController.doGet(MyController.java:262) [classes/:?]
    at com.company.controller.MyController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d73ec01b.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    ... suppressed 11 lines
    at com.company.controller.MyController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3de58f01.doGet(<generated>) [classes/:?]
    ... suppressed 85 lines
```

---

ADDENDUM: If you're also looking for a way to do this with JsonTemplateLayout because you export your logs to a service like Datadog/NewRelic/CloudWatch, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143208/6854489).